# BTX Halted. When I trying to install freeBSD 10.3 on my notebook I got this message:

Tags: freebsd, boot-loader

I'm trying to install FreeBSD-10.3 (FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso)
It's done perfectly on vmware virtual machine (with windows 10 host), but when I'm trying to install it on my notebook (ACER 5738z, 2GB DDR3 RAM, 250GB HDD, INTEL PENTIUM DUAL-CORE 14200) from burned DVD, I see this messages:

SATA Mode = IDE

```
 CD Loader 1.2

 Building the boot loader arguments Looking up /BOOT/LOADER... Found
 Relocating the loader and BTX Starting the BTX loader

 BTX loader 1.00 BTX version is 1.02 Console: internal video/keyboard
 BIOS CD is cd0 BIOS drive C: is disk0 BIOS 629kB/2020996kB available
 memory

 int=0000000d    err=00000000    efl=00010286    eip=0002d257
 eax=ffffff98    ebx=00000002    ecx=00035bc2    edx=ffffffff
 esi=00035bc2    edi=ffffffff    ebp=00092340    esp=00092324
 cs=002b   ds=003    es=0033    fs=0033   gs=0033   ss=0033
 cs:eip=8b 07 89 74 24 04 89 04-24 e8 ab 25 00 00 85 c0
        75 e7 8b 4f 0c 85 c9 0f-84 da 00 00 00 89 d8 83
ss:esp=ff ff ff ff c2 5b 03 00-70 0d 03 00 00 00 00 00
       c2 5b 03 00 8c 23 09 00-00 cc 0e 00 64 23 09 00
BTX halted
```

and when SATA Mode = AHCI

```
CD Loader 1.2
Building the boot loader arguments
Looking up /BOOT/LOADER... Found
Relocating the loader and BTX
Starting the BTX loader

BTX loader 1.00 BTX version is 1.02
Console: internal video/keyboard
BIOS CD is cd0
BIOS drive C: is disk0
BIOS 629kB/2020996kB available memory

FreeBSD/x86 bootstrap loader, Revision 1.1
(root@releng1.nyi.freebsd.org, Fri Mar 25 02:04:04:38 UTC 2016)
panic: zfree(0x7b3b7c30, 1056): wild pointer
--> Press a key on console to reboot <--
```

I already installed Ubuntu 15.10 x64 on this notebook, I'm using it every day.
Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the DVD/CD image was burnt correctly. I've had similar errors in the past when something went wrong during the burning process. First, check the checksum of the downloaded ISO image.

You can also check the burnt data on CD/DVD-R with (FreeBSD example):

```
dd if=/dev/cd0 bs=2048 | sha256
```